# How to find parallel and perpendicular parts of a force?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, vectors

I have a problem here that I have the answer to but don't know how to arrive to the answer. The question is this,

A 2.5kg object is on the incline plane shown below with phi = 34 degrees. It is pulled to the left with a tension force that is the same magnitude as the force of gravity. What is the perpendicular and parallel force of tension?

And this is what it looks like.
[image]

What is the correct way to go about a problem like this?

Comment: there is no theta in the diagram

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui its the circle with a line through it

Comment: $\phi$ is called phi, not theta.  Theta looks like this: $\theta$. Also, this is merely a drill problem for finding vector components.  What is your conceptual question?

Comment: @BillN How to find the unit vectors of the parallel and perpendicular forces. I'm not sure what i'm suppose to do with phi in order to get the right number to take the cosine of.

Comment: Each force vector is the hypotenuse of a right triangle. The other sides are parallel to your chosen coordinate directions (parallel and perpendicular to the plane, or parallel and perpendicular to gravity, etc). Use simple triangle geometry to find the angles in the triangle, then use trigonometry.  Don't tie cosine or sine to parallel or perpendicular. Look at the triangles.